# How to get members from Security Group to a File on Sharepoint - Logic App

Tags: azure, logic, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a logic app that would get members from security groups and then writes that to a CSV file, or any file located on a sharepoint folder.

I have gotten so far that I can get the members of multiple groups in a for each loop.
I am stuck at getting this in 1 single CSV.

The result should be the Name of the Group in column 1 and the email of the member in column2.
I've tried many multiple things already, but cant seem to figure it out.

This is my current set-up that returns bad parsed results for just 1 group.

[image]

How should I handle this?

See below a sample of the result of 1 Group:

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"headers": {
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
    "request-id": "76grrfc-3313-4103-8275-026e4e23777e",
    "client-request-id": "76fb31fc-3313rrrr5-026e4e23777e",
    "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": "{\"ServerInfo\":{\"DataCenter\":\"West Europe\",\"Slice\":\"E\",\"Ring\":\"5\",\"ScaleUnit\":\"000\",\"RoleInstance\":\"AM1PE00105B7\"}}",
    "x-ms-resource-unit": "3",
    "OData-Version": "4.0",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Date": "Tue, 29 Mar 2022 15:07:18 GMT",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; IEEE754Compatible=false; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Length": "1724"
},
"body": {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
            "businessPhones": [
                "+12222"
            ],
            "displayName": "Jaaa",
            "givenName": "a",
            "jobTitle": "aaa",
            "mail": "aaaa",
            "mobilePhone": "+0000",
            "officeLocation": "aaa",
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "aaa",
            "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
            "businessPhones": [
                "+12222"
            ],
            "displayName": "Jaaa",
            "givenName": "a",
            "jobTitle": "aaa",
            "mail": "aaaa",
            "mobilePhone": "+0000",
            "officeLocation": "aaa",
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "aaa",
            "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
            "businessPhones": [
                "+12222"
            ],
            "displayName": "Jaaa",
            "givenName": "a",
            "jobTitle": "aaa",
            "mail": "aaaa",
            "mobilePhone": "+0000",
            "officeLocation": "aaa",
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "aaa",
            "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
            "businessPhones": [
                "+12222"
            ],
            "displayName": "Jaaa",
            "givenName": "a",
            "jobTitle": "aaa",
            "mail": "aaaa",
            "mobilePhone": "+0000",
            "officeLocation": "aaa",
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "aaa",
            "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Error on CSV Table :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your array and created a flow using an approach I would use.

***Note:** The `@odata` syntax fails to parse so I had to remove the `@` sign when testing.  See how that affects you with your real life scenario.*

The high level steps are:

1. Create two arrays, one with the source data and the other with the CSV/destination data.
2. Loop through each element in your source array and `Compose` an object that contains only the two fields you want to include in your CSV data.
3. Append that new object to the CSV/destination array.
4. After the loop is done, write out the CSV/destination array to a CSV structure using the `Create CSV table` action.

This is the end result ...

[image: Result]

If you want to make sure the array is in the desired order, make sure you change the settings on the `For each` and turn concurrency off ...

[image: Concurrency]

This is the JSON definition that you can load into your own tenant for testing ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@variables('CSV Array')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "CSV Array",
                            "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "displayName": "@{items('For_each')['displayName']}",
                            "mail": "@{items('For_each')['mail']}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('JSON Array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_CSV_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_CSV_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "CSV Array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Source_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Source_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "JSON Array",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 1",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 1",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                },
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 2",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 2",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                },
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 3",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 3",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                },
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 4",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 4",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
How do I compose an object just containing my 2 values ?

Comment: That JSON definition I’ve included in the answer can be loaded into a LogicApp so you can see my answer in its entirety. Create a new app, go to the designer, then the code view and paste it in. When you go back to the designer, it’ll be my flow and you’ll see the object with just the two fields in the object.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Create CSV table` option, you should be able to specify custom headers and then be specific about what you pull back from each item in your array.

I took your JSON and created my own flow to show just that.

***Note:** The @odata syntax fails to parse so I had to remove the @ sign when testing. See how that affects you with your real life scenario.*

[image: Create CSV table]

The two expressions are in the definition below but for completeness, they are ...

**displayName** = `item()['displayName']`

**mail** = `item()['mail']`

This is the result ...

[image: Result]

This is the JSON definition that you can load into your own tenant for testing ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "header": "displayName",
                            "value": "@item()['displayName']"
                        },
                        {
                            "header": "mail",
                            "value": "@item()['mail']"
                        }
                    ],
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@variables('JSON Array')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Source_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "Initialize_Source_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "JSON Array",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 1",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 1",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                },
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 2",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 2",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                },
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 3",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 3",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                },
                                {
                                    "businessPhones": [
                                        "+12222"
                                    ],
                                    "displayName": "Jaaa 4",
                                    "givenName": "a",
                                    "id": "de2ae485-a578-439a-9bd2-991445a",
                                    "jobTitle": "aaa",
                                    "mail": "aaaa 4",
                                    "mobilePhone": "+0000",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                                    "officeLocation": "aaa",
                                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                                    "surname": "aaa",
                                    "userPrincipalName": "aaa"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response!
But unfortunately, it has not helped me much. I keep getting errors I cannot completely understand. I assume it is due to the note you added in your reply. 

Any idea how I can work around this?

Comment: You need to show a screenshot of your error or at least copy and paste the text into your question. Can you do that? Let’s not make assumptions.

Comment: Alright, but then let's describe the complete issue. 
You did not take into account the part that I loop multiple calls to the graph API.
so I make about 15 calls to receive members of groups.  (see screenshot)

So I think I'll have to select somehow the 2 headers first before I make a CSV table and then put all of them together in 1 CSV table. 

I'm a bit lost!

Comment: There another answer I put and then deleted. That shows how you can add each element from each array of the 15 calls to a single array. Then at the end, you can use the second answer to create your CSV table. Do you think that helps? It’s hard for me to help you in completeness because it sounds like you’ve got a few things going on and I can’t reproduce your flow in its entirety.

Comment: The sample data i've added you could use as 2 different calls. 
But let me update my post later with some more details that might help to structure my question!